# Symfony returns first element array

Tags: php, database, symfony

```
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->getLic();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getLic()
    {
        try {
            $conn = $this->db->getPDO()->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
            $conn->execute();
            $query = $conn->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            throw new \PDOException($exception->getMessage());
        }
        echo json_encode($query, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);

        return $query;
    }
```

The result should be:

```
{{11:1, 11:1, 11:1}, {12:2, 22:2, 32:2,}, {13:3, 23:3, 33:3}}
```

But it returns:

```
{11:1, 11:1, 11:1}
```

Comment: You probably wanted `fetchAll`. `fetch` returns one (the next) row.

Comment: The problem isn't symfony but the way you're using PDO. As soon as you get the entire result set everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, all worked